# My gradle java project does not find the log4j2.json

Tags: java, configuration, gradle, classpath, log4j2

Gradle version: 2.2.1
log4j2 version: 2.1 (I've also tried 2.0.2)
Java version: 1.8.0_25

The project layout is just the standard Gradle java-quickstart. I did put the log4j2.json under

```
projectHome/src/main/resources/log4j2.json
```

Here is the relevant part of my build.gradle:

```
task cook(type:JavaExec) {
    main = 'my.package.CookRunner'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But when I do "gradle cook", I always got the following message

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

What am I missing? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is that project hosted online?

Comment: No, this code is for a client with some NDA.

Comment: Could You please add `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.each { println it }` to *build.gradle* and see if *log4j2.json* is present there (or enclosing dir)?

Comment: Hi Opal, I got the following output: `projectRoot\build\classes\main, 
projectRoot\build\resources\main, ...`. the `log4j2.json` lies directly under the path `resources\main`. Not only does my application not find the `log4j2.json`, nor does it find my `application.properties`, which lies also directly under `resources\main`. What am I missing here, this is so frustrating. I'm working with a Windows box, by the way.

Comment: Without the access to the project source or at least sample project which reproduces the error it might difficult to help.

Comment: Was there a resolution for this?  I'm running into this exact issue.  I have a project with one simple unit test in it with the log4j2 config file in `src/test/resources`, print out the classpath, which shows that directory, but I get that same error.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 4):

Log4j [requires](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#JSON) some additional libs for parsing JSON configuration.
*"The JSON support uses the Jackson Data Processor to parse the JSON files. These dependencies must be added to a project that wants to use JSON for configuration".*

Add those to your dependencies section, and then refresh Gradle to download them:

```
compile group:"com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name:"jackson-core", version:'2.4.2'
compile group:"com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name:"jackson-databind", version:'2.4.2'
compile group:"com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name:"jackson-annotations", version:'2.4.2'
```